# MySQL select where row content is between two hours

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, between

I have this row:
[image]

How it's possible to get only the results between `07:00` and `00:00`? *07:00*, *23:59* and *00:00* in my case.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `".$today."` WHERE hour BETWEEN '07:00' AND '00:00'";
```

... returns nothing.

Comment: what is the datatype of hour ?

Comment: VARCHAR. Should I use something else?

Comment: Change it to to `time` datatype and try

Comment: Part of the problem stems from the fact that you have no PRIMARY KEY, so this 'table' isn't really a table at all (in a relational database sense)

Comment: Think the problem is that you are trying to use 00:00 as the end of the day, but MySQL considers it the beginning, so in comparisons it is LESS THAN 07:00 and hence the BETWEEN (in both varchar and time versions) looks for values > 07:00 and < 00:00 which don't exist.

Doing it the other way round gets you times > 00:00 and < 07:00 so that pulls some rows, but not the ones you want as its the set of times before 07:00 not after.

Including the date in the data may sort it if that is possible,00:00 rows can be set to the next day e.g.search for dates > 22/12/2013 07:00 and < 23/12/2013 00:00

Comment: @dethorpe - that's the OP's problem exactly - `00:00` is **beginning of day**, not end-of-day (midnight _may_ be recorded as `24:00`, but generally speaking that should be the _next_ day, and thus `00:00`...).  Nothing else matters/is relevant - not the datatype (he has a nice SARGable format), and not the fact that he hasn't listed a primary key.  er, Actually... @user3474451, are you using that as end-of-day, or just trying to get **through** end-of-day?

Answer (score 2):

Date stored as varchar makes it very difficult for query comparison and should be stored in proper datattype.

The workaround in your case i.e. using varchar stored time you can use something as

```
select * from 
table_name 
where 
TIME_FORMAT ( 
   str_to_date ( 
       replace (hour,':',''),'%H%i'
   ),'%H:%i'
) 
between '07:00' AND '23:59';
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04aba/4)**

Comment: Between `07:00-00:00` returns 0 results and between `00:00-07:00` returns _06:43_. I can change my datatype to `time`, but my time is in `G:i` format. What should I do?

Comment: @user3474451: Can you post table structure?

Comment: @Ravinder yes seems like it fails when the comparison is done on midnight 0 hours, I did not realize it before. Now One advice I can give to OP so as to store data with datetime Y-m-d H:i:s and it will make it easy for query. However I would love to see if there is some work around using current so please post as answer if you have some idea.

Comment: The replacement/conversion is unnecessary - the `:` is essentially a non-differentiating character in this case, and the data is in a nicely SARGable format - character `'07'` is less than character `'23'`, after all.  The chief problem is the OP's decision to use `00:00` to represent end-of-day, when it really means **start of the next day**.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tab 
where replace(hour,':','') 
between '0700' AND '2359'
OR replace(hour,':','') ='0000';
```

Comment: This returns _06:43_, _07:00_, _00:00_ and _00:40_.

Comment: Strictly speaking the replacement is unnecessary (the `:` is a non-differentiating character), but you're at least calling out the OP's special case.

Answer (score 0):

In general it seems a bit fuzzy problem/data structure setup as you you need to be careful if you refer to 07:00 -> 00:00, or 00:00 -> 07:00.

Working with TIMESTAMP will probably save a lot of headache, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE test(time1 TIMESTAMP, data VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO test(time1, data) VALUES('2014-05-09 07:00', 'kala1');
INSERT INTO test(time1, data) VALUES('2014-05-09 06:43', 'kala2');
INSERT INTO test(time1, data) VALUES('2014-05-09 23:59', 'kala3');
INSERT INTO test(time1, data) VALUES('2014-05-10 00:00', 'kala4');
INSERT INTO test(time1, data) VALUES('2014-05-10 00:40', 'kala5');
```

Then you can do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE time1 >= '2014-05-09 07:00' AND time1 <= '2014-05-10 00:00'
```

Comment: Depending on the situation, we don't know that there's a date value available.  It _would_ likely get him to stop using `00:00` as end-of-day, though.

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be more like

```
SELECT * FROM `".$today."` WHERE hour >= "7:00" AND hour <= "24:00";
```

This worked for me anyway.

Comment: This (with `07:00` instead of `7:00` and `"` escaped) returns _06:43_, _07:00_, _00:00_ and _00:40_.